# Page number won't show up on second slide in PPT 2013

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

No matter what slide layout I put in the second position of the Slide Master, when I close the Master, all slides using that layout don't show the slide number.  I have checked the slide # box in Master Layout; all slides have a page number box in the Master as well as the normal layout, etc. - I can't figure this out!

Comment: Have you got something layered above where the slide number should be (on slide 2)?

Comment: Refer the below link http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-powerpoint/page-numbers-not-showing-on-slides/67dbb342-65a5-4f98-9ee4-e53889782fc6